# Has anyone scanned ancient structures with x-rays or similar? And if so, were any major discoveries made by doing so?

Tags: ancient-history, science, research

Inspired by *curious'* [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/10557/2830); I now have my own:

Has anyone actually* scanned the pyramids or similar ancient structures with x-rays, gamma-rays, muons, ultrasound, thermal diffusion, gravity waves or other methods to figure out what's inside?

If so, have any major historical discoveries occurred solely because of such non-destructive scanning?

<sub>* Proposals to do so rather more common.</sub>

Comment: Interesting question. There could be breakthroughs in material science made by the ancients that the modern scientists could learn something about.

Comment: Well I was thinking more along the lines of hidden goodies, but yes there could also be architectural insights to help solidify [one or another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_pyramid_construction_techniques#Construction_method_hypotheses) construction hypotheses.

Comment: There is a whole major subdivision of archaeology called "Geophysics". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geophysical_survey_%28archaeology%29 As such, I'm voting to close this as too broad. If you want to focus it on architecture, or maybe even specifically the Pyramids, that might be better.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Absent of references as to which discoveries occurred to due to scanning; and which, when and by who the structure scanning occurred, I'd say this is the opposite of 'too broad'. Show me the money.

Comment: @LateralFractal: All the time, everywhere, by everyone. It's too broad. What "major" is is also opinion-based.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Hmm. Hmm. I'm not yet convinced. Let's see what commentary other users have. Perhaps there's a vast list of non-destructive geophysical [EM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum) surveys with profound new discoveries; or perhaps not. In this context 'major' means the EM survey serves as a primary non-corroborating source for historians.

Comment: @Lateral Fractal.  Simply do a search for Archaeology and Geophysics on Google and you'll come up with stuff that has been discovered.  It has been particularly helpful in finding new sites, analyzing more about sites like stonehenge (my favorite and some of the biggest break-throughs of which I am aware - which is reletively little), more info on mound builders and learning more about how early peoples altered the earth around them because you can map out ditches and furrows and things - I can't answer specifically about the pyramids, but as to other discoveries?Too numerous to list here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is a big ["oh yes, definitely"](http://www.academia.edu/4065052/Seeing_Beneath_the_Surface_at_Giza). And not just the Pyramids, [Geophysics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geophysical_survey_%28archaeology%29) is a standard technique in modern archaeology.

Just some random things discovered with geophys:

- [The Staffordshire Hoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staffordshire_Hoard).
- [Plumbing at Petra](http://antiquity.ac.uk/projgall/urban331/).
- The location and layout of [Athelney Abbey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athelney_Abbey).
- [A temple complex](http://egyptmanchester.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/curators-diary-8412-visiting-egypt-2-return-to-saqqara/) at Saqqara.

Comment: Tremaine's electromagnetic induction is an example, but the article as I far as I tell (it's very long and quite dense) seems to be showcasing the versatility of technology instead of any major discoveries solely due to the technology. I think this answer needs some elaboration.

Comment: What - There are no ancient aliens secretly buried in the Mayan pyramids and the sphinx! How cruel of you to shatter my myths that way.

Comment: If you know of any major discovery (novel insight/primary research) due to geophysic remote sensing - I'll give this answer the green tick.

Comment: @LateralFractal: Virtually no major discovery has been made without the use of geophys for the last 20 years or so. I added some random ones, chosen because I could find links for them.

Comment: Have a look at just about any episode of BBC's [Time Team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Team) to see good examples of geophysics in action on an archaeological dig.

Comment: don't forget the scanning of roman sculptures and reliefs to find the original colors. Biblical Archaeology Review has a recent issue on that. As many probably know on here, our view of white marble statues is biased by time; they were richly painted at first. It's funny that modern monochrome classical structures (think capital buildings) are really just artificially "distressed"